# On submit, not redirecting to action page PHP

Tags: php, html, post, form-submit

When i click on submit, it redirects and show Object Not Found.But the Url shows that it is on the action page.Please help to resolve this issue.....

//addprograms.php - action page
//funtions.php - common page that contain class and functions

HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 content">
    <div class="content-row">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title"><b>Add Programs</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form  role="form" class="form-horizontal" 
              action="../actions/addprograms.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Title" 
                   id="title" class="form-control" name="title">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                  for="description">Description</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea required="" class="form-control" 
                  placeholder="Description" rows="10" cols="30" 
                  name="description"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
               for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" 
                   name="uploadedfile">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                  <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" 
                   name="addprogramsubmit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
   </div><!-- content -->
```

addprograms.php

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
    if(isset($_POST['addprogramsubmit'])){
           echo '12';
           exit();
     }
?>
```

This is my functions.php file
functions.php(it is not complete)

```
<?php
 session_start();
 class Auth extends DB {

 function login($tablename, $username, $password) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT username,password FROM 
              $tablename WHERE username='$username'") or die("Error: " . 
               mysqli_error($this->con));;

    $login_result = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (($login_result['username'] == $username) && 
       ($login_result['password'] == $password)) {

                     $_SESSION['login_id'] = $username;            
    }
    return true;
 }

}

class DB {

public $con;

function __construct() {
    $this->con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "heatsds");
}

//    INSERT
function insert($tablename, $data = array(), $avoid_data = array()) {
    $i = 0;
    $fields = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach ($data as $col => $val) {
        if (!in_array($col, $avoid_data)) {
            if ($i === 0) {
                $fields .= "`" . $col . "`";
                $values .= "'" . $val . "'";
            } else {
                $fields .= ",`" . $col . "`";
                $values .= ",'" . $val . "'";
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT INTO $tablename ($fields) VALUES 
       ($values)");
}
function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->con);
}

}
```

[Image of the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsyAg.png)
[ERROR MESSAGE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5FJJ.png)

Comment: Show us the contents of `includes/functions.php';` and your directory structure..

Comment: Chukwuemeka Inya check the question now..added directory image and function.php

Answer (score 0):

your `<form>` has `action="../actions/addprograms.php"`, so it will search for `addprograms.php` file. In your listings it's only `actions.php`. Move `actions.php` content into `addprograms.php` and this should work.

Comment: action is a folder and the corresponding action file is addprograms.php........addprograms.php in "pages" folder contains the form,On that form submit,i need to redirect the action to addprograms.php file in "actions" folder......... Check the image of directory(link below code)